# Preloading images printed via Array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, preload

I am currently in a React project trying to print some images from an array of objects with an icon property that holds an image path/import.

It's presenting with some pretty apparent delay in the images loading, so I've been attempting to find a way to preload them as a group before printing them to the dom for better performance/aesthetic.

given this component:

```
import React from 'react';

const dict = [
{name: 'string', icon: require('../path/to/img.png')},
{name: 'string', icon: require('../path/to/img.png')},
{name: 'string', icon: require('../path/to/img.png')},
...
];

const Example = () => {
return(
   <div>
      {dict.map(item => return <img src={item.icon} />)}
   </div>
);
}

export default Example;
```

and the example array of objects at the top of it, how would I go about preloading those images so they all appear at the exact same time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using CRA/webpack, the requires just give string paths rather than actually fetching the image content, so it's an issue with how the browser queues image loading. I'm not clear exactly what you'd want the user to experience, but you could try to cache the images or hide them until they're done loading.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want, hide them until they're done loading. I could see how i would do this with one image at a time by using onload and hitting a function to add a class or something. What would the best way to do an entire group of them at once instead of one at a time like iterating through them one at a time would do?